# JS mini-game in grid, browser frozen after first replication

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, web-worker

I'm trying to create a small game that replicate neighbors cells in a grid. I use a web worker that draw replicate cells every seconds. I'm able to replicate the first second. If my initial cell is row3col3, the new replicated cells will be :

row3col2, row3col4
row2col3, row4col3

**The problem is, after the first second (and the replication), the game freezes, and i'm not able to do something. Can't click on cells, etc.**

**EDIT : After few seconds, it go to '00:02' but Chrome crashed "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong...' [RELOAD]**

**EDIT 2 : After looking on the memory used, It appears I have an memory overflow, 16000 Mb ! My method is bad, so.**

I know my code is not really optimised, and I think that is the problem. Unfortunatly, i'm not able to do more efficient code, so I ask some help to you guys, to give me some ways to explore.

Here the code :

```
var lastClicked;
var cellTab = Array();
var replicant = Array();
var newReplicant = Array();
var count = 5;

var rows = 20;
var cols = 20;

var randomRow = Math.floor((Math.random() * rows));
var randomCol = Math.floor((Math.random() * cols));



var grid = clickableGrid(rows, cols,randomRow,randomCol,cellTab, function(el,row,col,i){
    console.log("You clicked on element:",el);
    console.log("You clicked on row:",row);
    console.log("You clicked on col:",col);
    console.log("You clicked on item #:",i);

    $(el).addClass('clicked');

    lastClicked = el;
});

document.getElementById("game").appendChild(grid);

function clickableGrid( rows, cols, randomRow, randomCol, cellTab, callback ){
    var i=0;
    var grid = document.createElement('table');
    grid.className = 'grid';
    for (var r=0;r<rows;++r){
        var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        for (var c=0;c<cols;++c){
            var cell = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            $(cell).addClass('row'+r+'col'+c);
            if(randomCol == c && randomRow == r)
            {
                storeCoordinate(r, c, replicant);
                $(cell).css('background', '#000000');
            }
            storeCoordinate(r, c, cellTab);
            cell.addEventListener('click',(function(el,r,c,i){
                return function(){
                    callback(el,r,c,i);
                }
            })(cell,r,c,i),false);
        }
    }
    return grid;
}


function storeCoordinate(xVal, yVal, array)
{
    array.push({x: xVal, y: yVal});
}

function replicate(replicant)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < replicant.length; i++) {
      console.log(replicant);
        var supRowX = replicant[i].x-1;
        var supRowY = replicant[i].y;
        storeCoordinate(supRowX, supRowY, newReplicant);
        var subRowX = replicant[i].x+1;
        var subRowY = replicant[i].y;
        storeCoordinate(subRowX, subRowY, newReplicant);
        var supColsX = replicant[i].x;
        var supColsY = replicant[i].y-1;
        storeCoordinate(supColsX, supColsY, newReplicant);
        var subColsX = replicant[i].x;
        var subColsY = replicant[i].y+1;
        storeCoordinate(subColsX, subColsY, newReplicant);
    }
}

function drawReplicant(replicant, cellTab)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < replicant.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray(replicant[i], cellTab))
        {
            $('.row'+replicant[i].x+'col'+replicant[i].y).css('background', '#000000');
        }
    }
}

var w = null; // initialize variable

// function to start the timer
function startTimer()
{
   // First check whether Web Workers are supported
   if (typeof(Worker)!=="undefined"){
      // Check whether Web Worker has been created. If not, create a new Web Worker based on the Javascript file simple-timer.js
      if (w==null){
         w = new Worker("w.countdown.js");
      }
      // Update timer div with output from Web Worker
      w.onmessage = function (event) {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = event.data;
        console.log(event.data);
        replicate(replicant);
        replicant = newReplicant;
        drawReplicant(replicant, cellTab);
      };
   } else {
      // Web workers are not supported by your browser
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers ...";
   }
}

// function to stop the timer
function stopTimer()
{
   w.terminate();
   timerStart = true;
   w = null;
}

startTimer();
```

And here, the web worker :

```
var timerStart = true;

function myTimer(d0)
{
   // get current time
   var d=(new Date()).valueOf();
   // calculate time difference between now and initial time
   var diff = d-d0;
   // calculate number of minutes
   var minutes = Math.floor(diff/1000/60);
   // calculate number of seconds
   var seconds = Math.floor(diff/1000)-minutes*60;
   var myVar = null;
   // if number of minutes less than 10, add a leading "0"
   minutes = minutes.toString();
   if (minutes.length == 1){
      minutes = "0"+minutes;
   }
   // if number of seconds less than 10, add a leading "0"
   seconds = seconds.toString();
   if (seconds.length == 1){
      seconds = "0"+seconds;
   }

   // return output to Web Worker
   postMessage(minutes+":"+seconds);
}

if (timerStart){
   // get current time
   var d0=(new Date()).valueOf();
   // repeat myTimer(d0) every 100 ms
   myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer(d0)},1000);
   // timer should not start anymore since it has been started
   timerStart = false;
}
```

Maybe it's because I use jQuery ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the game freezes"? Does the browser lock up and stop responding, or is it just that your game stops responding to click events? In the first case, it's likely an infinte loop. If it's the latter, something is preventing the click event from being attached to the elements. Try adding a load more console statements and watch to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: The browser seem to stop responding, console.log(event.data); should return '00:01', '00:02', '00:03'... But blocks at '00:01' with freeze. I can't select the '00:01' string.. **EDIT : After few seconds, it go to '00:02' but Chrome crashed "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong...' [RELOAD]**

Comment: After looking on the memory used, It appears I have an memory overflow, 16000 Mb... wtf. My method appears to be so bad, I need to change it...